# Error "Could NOT find PythonLibs" when building Root

Tags: linux, cmake, root-framework

I got this message when I tried to install the Root software onto Ubuntu Linux.
Please give me advice. What is the problem and how can I manage this?

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.17.1") 
-- ROOT default compression algorithm: zlib
-- Found GCC. Major version 7, minor version 4
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found a 64bit system
-- Found GNU compiler collection
-- Performing Test GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
-- Performing Test GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI - Success
-- ROOT Platform: linux
-- ROOT Architecture: linuxx8664gcc
-- Build Type: RelWithDebInfo
-- Compiler Flags:  -std=c++11 -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-noexcept-type -pipe  -Wshadow -Wall -W -Woverloaded-virtual -fsigned-char -pthread 
-- Looking for ZLib
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Looking for Freetype
-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so (found version "2.8.1") 
-- Looking for PCRE
-- Could NOT find PCRE (missing: PCRE_INCLUDE_DIR PCRE_PCRE_LIBRARY) 
-- PCRE not found. Switching on builtin_pcre option
-- Looking for LZMA
-- LZMA not found. Switching on builtin_lzma option
-- Building LZMA version 5.2.4 included in ROOT itself
-- Looking for xxHash
-- Could NOT find xxHash (missing: xxHash_LIBRARY xxHash_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- xxHash not found. Switching on builtin_xxhash option
-- Looking for LZ4
-- Could NOT find LZ4 (missing: LZ4_LIBRARY LZ4_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- LZ4 not found. Switching on builtin_lz4 option
-- Looking for X11
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- X11_INCLUDE_DIR: /usr/include
-- X11_LIBRARIES: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- X11_Xpm_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include
-- X11_Xpm_LIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXpm.so
-- X11_Xft_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include
-- X11_Xft_LIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so
-- X11_Xext_INCLUDE_PATH: 
-- X11_Xext_LIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Could NOT find GIF (missing: GIF_LIBRARY GIF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.6.34") 
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Building AfterImage library included in ROOT itself
-- Looking for GSL
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Could NOT find GSL: Found unsuitable version "", but required is at least "1.10" (found GSL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND)
-- GSL not found. Set variable GSL_DIR to point to your GSL installation
--                Alternatively, you can also enable the option 'builtin_gsl' to build the GSL libraries internally'
--                For the time being switching OFF 'mathmore' option
-- Looking for python
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.6 (found version "3.6.9") 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:262 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/modules/SearchInstalledSoftware.cmake:9 (_find_package)
  cmake/modules/SearchInstalledSoftware.cmake:441 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:159 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kidou/다운로드/root-6.18.04/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/kidou/다운로드/root-6.18.04/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: @KamilCuk the root tag description https://stackoverflow.com/tags/root/info lists the common confusion with the software listed under the root-framework tag.

Answer (score 2):

(Essentially an update to squareskittles answer)

The official list of prerequisits is hosted by the root team [here](https://root.cern.ch/build-prerequisites). For Ubuntu they list

> Required packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install git dpkg-dev cmake g++ gcc binutils libx11-dev \
> libxpm-dev libxft-dev libxext-dev
> ```
>
> Optional packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gfortran libssl-dev libpcre3-dev \
> xlibmesa-glu-dev libglew1.5-dev libftgl-dev libmysqlclient-dev \
> libfftw3-dev libcfitsio-dev graphviz-dev \
> libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev libldap2-dev python-dev libxml2-dev \
> libkrb5-dev libgsl0-dev libqt4-dev
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are building the CERN ROOT software. The [CERN ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) software has several [dependencies](http://tylern4.github.io/InstallRoot/) that are needed to enable all of its features. You can install them with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran libssl-dev libpcre3-dev xlibmesa-glu-dev libglew1.5-dev libftgl-dev libmysqlclient-dev libfftw3-dev graphviz-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev libldap2-dev libxml2-dev libkrb5-dev libgsl0-dev libqt4-dev
```

This list of dependencies was taken from the linked documentation for installing ROOT (from 2017), although there are probably more recent installation instructions more applicable to your version of ROOT.